# How To Direct Magento installation path in subfolder to main domain name

Tags: magento, subdirectory, installation-path

I have installed Magento 1.7.0.2 to mydomain.com/mag

(mydomain - is the primary registered domain at my hosting account)
(mag - is any subfolder)

As my website in testing mode, if anything goes wrong, i simply have to delete the “mag” folder and also it does not overwrite any files under public_html.

But if i install on directly to root directly public_html, then it may overwrite few files or folders and if i want to revert any time, then i cannot do that manually.

As i don’t even know the exact folder and file default structure under public_html prior to magento installation.

(I did that once by mistake, that happened)

Now at frontend the site URL will be mydomain.com/mag

But i want, if customers type the http://www.mydomain.com, they will be able to see the LIVE website instead of typing http://www.mydomain.com/mag

How do i do that

Also, will this be OK for SEO part.

Do we need to do this in Magento backend.
or
Do we need to do with hosting company by setting sub-domain type
or
By telling Simple scripts the installation to change the installation folder from mydomain.com/mag to www.mydomain.com

Please do suggest how can i do so.

Regards

Comment: you should put it in public_html just. If you think files there are going to get lost, just copy them to a different folder first so you can restore them anytime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `System > Config > Web` you will find the following settings for your 'base url'. To update this you will have to perform the following 3 steps:

**Step 1: Set the default store to the proper base url**

[image: web configuration settings]

Notice that the base url has the subfolder defined.

**Step 2: Set your STORE VIEW base url to the root url**

Using your dropdown on the left, change the "Current configuration scope" to your store view [NOT DEFAULT]

[image: store view switcher]

To change the base url value, uncheck 'use website' and enter your new base url:

[image: new base url]

Also, double-check in the same screen that your Session file management cookie path is set to the root folder of your site and that the domain is correct:

[image: cookie management]

**Step 3 [also used for multiple store management]**

Finally, and this is important, you need to copy the index.php file, .htaccess file, and symlink your media,skin and js folders to your root directory, because they're only available to your subfolder Magento base install right now - we need to let your main domain know where to look for Magento!

From secure shell in your *Magento installation* directory (in your case, mag) as sudoer:

```
sudo cp index.php ../
sudo cp .htaccess ../
sudo ln -s js ../
sudo ln -s skin ../
sudo ln -s media ../
```

Your admin will still be available at `yoursite.com/mag/admin`.

Edit your index.php file in this main webroot (the file you just copied) and update it around line 45:

`$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';`

Change this to :

`$mageFilename = 'cart/app/Mage.php';`

Where 'mag' is the subfolder. In your case you'd use the folder named 'mag'. Finally, you *need to clear the cache* for these changes to take effect.

**Step 4: Multi-store [optional]**

If you have more than one store, they can all be served this way, but you need to edit the index.php file to give it the correct store code. More info about that can be found here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work

Comment: Thank a lot philwinkle. Your explaination using images helped me a lot to understand. Terrific tutorial, amazing. I will surely try this. One thing- Step 3 is bit confusing for me.
What is meant by "symlink your media, skin..". What to actually do and how.

Comment: Which .htaccess file i need to copy as i think there are few inside everywhere in folders.
What if i don't have access to Secure Shell.
Actually i don't know how to use it.
Also, will it effect or degrade any SEO part, do i have to do some additional tweaks to improve for search engines. Will everything be done automatically.

Comment: Specifically the htaccess of your main webroot of the Magento install, the one that has the `index.php` file in it.

Comment: I'm updating it now to be more clear, it's for both the multi store mode and for the parent folder. I will make it more descriptive!

Comment: OK, all set. Basically you need to copy the index and .htaccess from your /mag/ folder to the webroot folder (one folder up from /mag/) and then edit index.php to tell Magento where the main Mage App file is!

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming. Can you please let me know about my previouse left over queries too. About "symlink your media, skin.." and about SEO part, if i applied the change this way.

Comment: Also, one more thing, there used to be a "URL Redirect" method provided by Shared Web Hosting providers. Can we use this method to rediret our "../mag" URL to "Main to webroot or main URL. If so, then how.

Comment: I would advise against using any Shared Hosting redirects. If you want more specific help on your particular situation I suggest we move this to chat!

Comment: 1. Do we need to modify Secure as well? 2. I did this, except I wasn't su. Didn't work now. What are the issues with changing all the Unsecure items to the subfolder? Seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

i must say that figuring out how to symbolic link was a hassle and i still couldnt figure it out. All the other steps worked fine except i copied my htaccess and my index.php and i just pasted it to my root. So for those who are having trouble, i found a better solution instead of symbolic link for "media, skin and JS" folders. In your magento admin. System>config under general click web. just change your base skin, media and js to the folder you want them to point to...

ex: {{unsecure_base_url}}cart/skin/

worked for me. Hope it works for anyone with the same problem. Ohh and im using magento 1.8.1 Thanks again @philwinkle