# Magento 2.2.5 redirect from sub to root

Tags: magento2.2

I am new to Magento. Successfully installed/implemented Magento 2.2.5. However, I installed Magento as subfolder in root. And my cart shows as `mydomainname.example/magento`. I want to change it so public does not see 'magento' in my URL. I found several posts regarding it.e.g. [How To Direct Magento installation path in subfolder to main domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749733/how-to-direct-magento-installation-path-in-subfolder-to-main-domain-name).  My challenge is that Magento 2.2.5 `index.php` file does not  have any code line 45 that I can edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to move all folders from Magento to the root.

But if you need subfolders anyway you can use one of this solutions:

1) Open apache or nginx settings and specify the Magento folder as the "root directory" of your website.

2) You can also create file at the root, name it `index.php` and the content will be `<?php require __DIR__ . '/magento/index.php'; ?>`

Comment: Thank you. I will try these options over the weekend.

Comment: @Mainer does it help you?

Comment: No it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing the referenced solution is a Magento 1, it's a very different framework from Magento 2!

In your case I think you need to edit the `.htaccess` in the parent folder like in [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148290/installing-magento2-subfolder-url)

```
# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks  #Include this line if you are using Godaddy hosting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)magento
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ magento/$1 [L]
```

at last, I recommend https://magento.stackexchange.com/ for the magento related questions as it's dedicated to Magento

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will move to Magento.stackexchange. I know the solution link I embedded was for Magento 1; however I had come across same solution for Magento2 implementations with same dilemma. My .htaccess file is pretty large, and it has following lines at the beginning:

Comment: RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomainname.com/Magento/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: No it did not help.